# Material-UI TextField onChange doesn't invoke function in a test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I'm learning both Jest and React and experimenting with Material-UI. I wrote this simple test just to check how things work:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent, configure} from '@testing-library/react';

import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';

configure({ testIdAddribute: 'id' });

describe('Testing events', () => {

  test('onChange', () => {
    const onChangeMock = jest.fn();
    
    const { getByTestId } = render(
      <TextField id="test" onChange={onChangeMock} type="text" />
    );
    
    fireEvent.change(getByTestId('test', { target: { value: 'foo' } }));
    expect(onChangeMock.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

But this test fails:

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 1
    Received: 0
```

What am I not understanding here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`getByTestId()`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#bytestid) will look for `data-testid` attribute, not `id`. Try changing your code from

```js
<TextField id="test" onChange={onChangeMock} />
```

To

```js
<TextField inputProps={{ 'data-testid': 'test' }} onChange={onChangeMock} />
```

Now in your code

> ```js
> fireEvent.change(getByTestId('test', { target: { value: 'foo' }}));
> expect(onChangeMock.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
> ```

When simulating key presses from the user, you should use [`@testing-library/user-event`](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event) and call `user.type()` instead of firing the the `onChange` event yourself manually.

You can also use [`.toHaveBeenCalledTimes(number)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavebeencalledtimesnumber) matcher to assert how many times the function had been invoked.

And finally, you should use `getByRole()` instead of `getByTestId()` because the user will see the `TextField` (`getByRole('textbox')`) instead of `data-testid` attribute of the element which you can only see when inspecting the elements.

See the [Which query should I use?](https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-which-query) to know more about the philosophy of RTL.

Put it together, you will have something like this:

```js
import { screen } from '@testing-library/dom'
import user from '@testing-library/user-event'

...

const onChangeMock = jest.fn();
    
render(<TextField onChange={onChangeMock} />);

const input = screen.getByRole('textbox')

user.type(input, 'foo')
expect(onChangeMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
```

Comment: Awesome. It works. Thanks. I do have one comment and one question if you don't mind. First, I had the `configure({ testIdAttribute: 'id' });` statement in the code because to my understanding TextField doesn't take `testId` attribute. I kept the `id` attribute and the test still work. As for my question, I understand what you are saying about using `getByRole`, but I ran into a problem using this when in TextField the attribute was `text="password` because input of type password then it seems there is no corresponding role. What should I do then? Also, what should I do if there are 2_ boxes?

Comment: Sorry I miss the `configure` detail when reading your question. Yes you're right,  you can't pass `data-testid` directly to `TextField`, you need to pass it to `inputProps.data-testid`. See [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/64580102material-ui-textfield-onchange-doesnt-invoke-function-in-a-test64580149-yuo9m?file=/demo.js:474-484) demo for more detail. @user2921009

Comment: About which role to apply, you can see the full list of valid roles [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#docconformance), in cases where your element has no suitable role, fallback to `getByLabelText()` or  `getByPlaceholderText()` as suggested by the [priority list](https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-which-query). @user2921009

Comment: You can also play around in this interactive [playground](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-external#playground) to discover what query should be applied to your element @user2921009